# Get next element of array inside a foreach loop in perl without using next/skipping to next iteration of loop

Tags: arrays, perl, foreach

I am new to perl and am facing some problem in skipping to next element of an array inside a foreach loop without reiterating the loop. Suppose I have the following case where I am going through a array using a foreach loop.

```
 foreach (@lines){  
     ...  
     print "$_";     #print current line  
     if (cond){      #this condition is met by one "line" in @lines  
        #goto next line;  
        $_=~s/expr/substitute_expr/g;     #substitute in the next line  
      }  
     ...
 }
```

Is it possible to do this in perl. With a file handler it is possible using the <> operator, as follows

```
foreach $line (<FILE>){  
    print "$line\n";        #print this line  
    $line = <FILE>;  
    print "$line";        #print next line  
}
```

Is there any way this can be replicated with an array.
*Is there any way to do this* **without** *using* **next** *or* **a duplicate array**

Comment: What's wrong with `next`?

Comment: @Cyx If a given $line triggers an `if`statement, and the block of code used within this `if` statement needs the next element of the array, then `next` fails to achieve the desired end.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use array indexes:

```
for my $i (0 .. $#lines) {
    # ...
    print $lines[$i];
    if (cond()) {
        $lines[ $i + 1 ] =~ s/pattern/replace/g;
    }
}
```

This will, however, process the "next" line again in the next iteration of the loop. If you do not want that, you can use the C-style for:

```
for (my $i = 0; $i < $#list ; $i++) {
    # ...
}
```

A more advanced technique would be to define an *iterator:*

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;


sub iterator {
    my $list = shift;
    my $i = 0;
    return sub {
        return if $i > $#$list;
        return $list->[$i++];
    }
}


my @list = qw/a b c d e f g h/;
my $get_next = iterator(\@list);

while (my $member = $get_next->()) {
    print "$member\n";
    if ('d' eq $member) {
        my $next = $get_next->();
        print uc $next, "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: I like that you used a closure in your iterator! Good solution: keeps the while loop neat and clear by keeping annoying indexes isolated in the iterator. Especially useful if you are parsing output and want to pull several lines from the "list" at intervals.

Comment: I like the closure iterator solution, but it's performance is unlike a normal foreach loop, in that it will unfortunately fail for any array element which is zero, an empty string, or undefined.  I've posted an edited solution below.

Answer (score 1):

This is a modification of choroba's closure answer which will work with all arrays (i.e. arrays which contain values like `0`, `""`, and `undef`), hence performing more like a typical foreach loop.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

sub iterator {
    my $list = shift;
    my $i = 0;
    return sub {
       if (defined $_[0] and $i > $#$list){
           return 0;
       }
       elsif (defined $_[0]){
           return 1;
       }
       else{
           return $list->[$i++];
       }
    }
}

my @list = qw/a b c d e f g h 0 1 2 3/;
my $get_next = iterator(\@list);

while ($get_next->("cycle through all array elements")) {
    my $member = $get_next->();
    print "$member\n";
    if ('d' eq $member) {
        my $next = $get_next->();
        print uc $next, "\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Use a count loop as in:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @list = (1, 2, 3);
# as the item after the last can't be changed,
# the loop stops before the end
for (my $i = 0; $i < (scalar @list - 1); ++$i) {
    if (2 == $list[$i]) {
        $list[$i + 1] = 4;
    }
}

print join ',', @list;
```

output:

```
perl countloop.pl
1,2,4
```

Comment: `scalar @list - 1` is same as `@list - 1` and as `$#list`

Comment: @mpapec - as they are the same - why comment on my using the one I like best?

Comment: Your `for` loop never iterates over the last element. If that is intended you should put a comment next to that line.